# Have a slicer of account regions, but need to filter the data by a related entity field of slicer

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, dynamics-365

I'm building a Power BI dashboard for D365 CE. I have a slicer with Account Regions which Slices the Opportunities. However, client only wants to show Opportunities with Account Regions with certain Account Territories.  I.e.., show Opportunities in Any region that ARE  NOT of Account Territory 1.  Region is a related entity to Account.  I've been fighting this one for hours. So in short, need slicer to include all regions but filter data by certain account types in associated with the region.

[image]

As you can see from above image, The Territory entity is the DIM and the Opportunity Entity is the FACT.  I am using the slicer to slice by ta_Region as circled. However, I need to only show results from fact table where the Territory field circled below ta_region in the picture != 1

The following is the visualization:

[image]

From above picture, you can see that in the top left corner I am slicing by Region, but need to filter the Opportunities in the bottom (blued out) by Terrtitory from the first picture.

Comment: Show sample & result expected

Comment: @ArunVinoth updated question with model